# Random euler code

Tags: java

Hi so i was attempting problem 35 from the euler project, circular primes. The problem was:
The number, 197, is called a circular prime because all rotations of the digits: 197, 971, and 719, are themselves prime.

How many circular primes are there below one million?

[Edit: i used integer to string conversion method that worked]

Comment: well, 1. the cloud-directory isn't open for all, 2. please **always** post the code directly with the question. Links should only be provided for additional online-resources. See the guide for more info. And in this example it'd be most likely a lot simpler, if you'd just directly post the code related to the question instead of us searching through your code for the part that is related to the issue.

Comment: sorry about that and the thing is i am not sure if that is the problem

Comment: NP :) I'd recommend you work over that code entirely. ATM it's extremely inefficient. Start by generating a `HashSet` to store all primes. That'll save you a lot of time on prime-checks. Your current code would run atleast several thousand checks for pime-numbers via linear-search for a divisor. And use a sieve of erathostenes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for the search. And generating an array of all numbers in range [1 , 1000000] is just a waste of memory. As for the rotation itself: the result of `checkPrime` is entirely ignored, which might be  the issue.

Comment: yes, as I've already said, generate a set of all primes and use that set to check, if a number is a prime. Use the Sieve of Erathostenes (or Atkin, if you don't mind a solution that is a bit more complex, but also faster) to speedup the generation of the set of primes. And the search itself can aswell be improved by simply removing each number after you checked whether it's prime and aswell all rotations of the number that are prime, to reduce the set of primes and avoid duplicate checks.

Comment: ok thnx i understand what to do

Comment: First feedback for everyone who is interested in my feedback: At least READ your own question. You have many typos in there.

Comment: would it be possible to sort through an array to have true values appear first

Answer (score 1):

This part will run forever:

```
 while (input > 0)//To determine the number of digits {
     copyInput /= 10;
     numDigits++; 
 }
```

Also, use of Math.pow() is suspect.  That is floating-point not integer computation and all sorts of weird things can happen.  Try converting to a String instead, using String operations to remove from back and push to front or vice-versa, then convert the string back to an integer.